# TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function - On Build only

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux

We have a React app that has been absolutely fine for 2 years.

Recently we had to get https running locally for some device function testing, and had to upgrade some libraries.

```
"react-scripts": "3.4.1",
"react-scripts-ts": "4.0.8",    
"react": "16.13.1",

"react-app-rewired": "1.6.2",

"start:app": "cross-env react-app-rewired start --scripts-version react-scripts-ts",
"build": "npm run build:css && react-app-rewired build --scripts-version react-scripts-ts",
```

Running the app locally is now fine, however when deployed the app throws these errors,

```
index.browser.js:1195 Uncaught TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function
    at index.browser.js:1195
    at index.browser.js:1194
    at Module.<anonymous> (index.browser.js:1186)
    at n (index.browser.js:15)
    at Object.e.exports (index.browser.js:327)
    at n (index.browser.js:15)
    at e.exports (index.browser.js:51)
    at Object.<anonymous> (index.browser.js:5)
    at f ((index):1)
    at Module.1301 (getScene.ts:12)
```

Any idea where that is coming from? GetScene is a Redux selector.

Answer (score 0):

This was an error in a component, I've removed that an building as normal. Something related to an out of date uglify version apparently.